# Function in C returns the correct value even without specifying what it should return

Tags: c, function, return

A question arose that is not very clear to me because it had not happened to me until now and that is that while I was solving exercises from the C book, reviewing my previous codes I noticed that in a function of type int, I forgot to put the return and it still returned me the value I wanted, I am also testing emacs, and when I activate the LSP I get an alert, but when I compile it it does not give me any warning that the return is missing since I have always used to place a return to functions that are not of type void, so my question is why does this happen? I had understood that this happened in the main but not in its own functions. I attached a screenshot of the function and the source code (the "minor" identifier, I only put it in to see if something happened and an error was returned).

```
int long_word(int *m) {
  int min = 0;
  int max = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
    if (m[i] > max) {
      max = m[i];
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Undefined behavior.

Comment: You need to bump up the warning level on your compiler. It might "work" (experimentally, for you, sometimes, maybe), but it's undefined behavior.

Comment: *so my question is why does this happen?* -- "I bought a rope that is rated to hold 500 pounds.  I tied 600 pounds to the rope, but it didn't break.   My friend bought the same rope, tied 600 pounds to it, and it broke immediately.  Why did this happen?"  -- That is undefined behavior.

Comment: Note: If you are using GCC and not compiling with `-Wall -Wextra`, you are shooting yourself in the foot.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I think that's a rather uncharitable take. This is not obvious, and frankly, really shit language design. We all know this, we're just too used it because that's how it's always been (and can't be fixed for backwards compat concerns).

Comment: Back in the '70s there were decent reasons for this not being an error. But in the modern era, I've seen optimizing compilers generate output that does very strange things, at least in C++, whether the program exits the function without reaching a return or not. I'm of the opinion that turning on the optimizer should make exit without a return a hard error.

Comment: I like `-g -O -Wall -Wextra -fsanitize=address,undefined` for gcc flags.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does flowing off the end of a non-void function without returning a value not produce a compiler error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1610030/why-does-flowing-off-the-end-of-a-non-void-function-without-returning-a-value-no)

Comment: Note that if we compile your program with optimization on (e.g. `-O2`), the generated function is a _single_ `retq` instruction. The compiler realized that all the code [ultimately] did nothing because no global variables were changed and the function had _no_ return value. So, it performed "dead code elimination". That's why it's important [_critical_] to compile with `-Wall -Wextra -Werror`. Otherwise, one could spend days trying to debug this by running the program (even under `gdb`) for something that the compiler could catch in a few seconds.

Comment: The most dangerous outcome for UB: a function that "works."

Comment: Another duplicate: [C function returns correct result but no return statement is given, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39054285/c-function-returns-correct-result-but-no-return-statement-is-given-why?rq=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program exhibits undefined behavior.  The following, for instance, returns `0` for me which is the last rather than the correct value of the array `m`:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int long_word(int *m) {
    int min = 0;
    int max = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
        if (m[i] > max) {
            max = m[i];
        }
    }
}

int main(void) {
    printf("%d\n", long_word((int []) {1, 2, 7, 13, 421, 2, 7, 13, 42, 12, 582, 32, 21, 42, 0}));
}
```

On AMD64/Linux the return value is in the register `rax` and it just so happens that compiled code uses the `rax` register to store `m[i]` as it evaluates the condition `if (m[i] > max)`:

```
(gdb) disass /m
[...]
7                       if (m[i] > max) {
   0x0000555555555158 <+31>:    mov    -0x8(%rbp),%eax
   0x000055555555515b <+34>:    cltq
   0x000055555555515d <+36>:    lea    0x0(,%rax,4),%rdx
   0x0000555555555165 <+44>:    mov    -0x18(%rbp),%rax
   0x0000555555555169 <+48>:    add    %rdx,%rax
   0x000055555555516c <+51>:    mov    (%rax),%eax
=> 0x000055555555516e <+53>:    cmp    %eax,-0x4(%rbp)
   0x0000555555555171 <+56>:    jge    0x55555555518c <long_word+83>
[...]
(gdb) i r rax
rax       0x0
```

You want to increase the warning level for your compiler to catch this.  `gcc -Wall` does the trick for me:

```
1.c:4:13: warning: unused variable ‘min’ [-Wunused-variable]
    4 |         int min = 0;
      |             ^~~
1.c:11:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
   11 | }
```

Comment: Escalate with `-Werror` to have your compiler force you to fix this.